# What is the optimal way of saving chat messages to database in MERN stack?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, chat, mern

Note: I don't want the code written out for me, I only want to know the theoretical information.

Unlike comments and most other data we store in the database, there can be hundreds of messages sent and received at a single time. So, I thought that saving every single message to the database one at a time will have too many queries to the database consequently increasing the cost. Is there any better way of going about this? What is the standard or optimal industry way this is usually done? Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: There is no standard way. You could buffer pending writes in memory and write them as batch operations. Much more efficient, but then you risk data loss if your system crashes before pending messages are persisted. You could mitigate this by replicating this in-memory store somehow, but then it's adding to the cost again.

Comment: You could reduce hosting costs by not using cloud pay-per-request databases and running your own DB servers instead. On the other hand, your payroll goes up as you'll need someone to do this. It's all about tradeoffs.

Comment: so saving each message one by one sounds the best way upto this point, I was thinking about saving the messages in the user device and then backing it up if they want to the way whatsapp works, can I use realm or sqlite for this, it's a react-native app btw

Comment: That is another way you could go, yes.